# How to construct css_selector to work with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

Using CSS selector in selenium python, I'm trying to log in to webpage automatically.

Instead of using:

```
driver.find_element_by_id()
```

I wanna practice using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector()
```

So i coded it like :

```
userId = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[id = "pass"]')
userId.send_keys('blabla78945@gmail.com')
```

But it wont find the element that its supposed to be typed in. Whats the problem of this case?

Comment: Hello, welcome on Stackoverflow! I don't think `input[id = "pass"]` is a valid thing, you can try using `input[type=password]`

Comment: also you need to check that your code isn't running too fast because many times the page don't have time to load up , see browser.wait() until methods

Comment: first show real URL - different pages may need different solutions.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should use `find_element` without **s**  to get single element. Now you use `find_elements` with **s** so get list of elements and you may need `[0]` to work with first element on list. Maybe first use `print( userId )` to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. If you were able to send a *character sequence* within the desired element using `find_elements_by_id()` as follows:

```
userId = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
userId.send_keys('blabla78945@gmail.com')
```

Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you can achieve the same as follows:

- Using the `id` attribute only as a `css_selector`:

  ```
  userId = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#pass")
  userId.send_keys('blabla78945@gmail.com')
  ```
- Using the *tagName* `<input>` along with `id` attribute as a `css_selector`:

  ```
  userId = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#pass")
  userId.send_keys('blabla78945@gmail.com')
  ```

> **Note**: You need to use **`find_element_by_css_selector()`** which returns the desired webelement, where as `find_elements_by_css_selector()` returns a *List* and you can't invoke `send_keys()` on a *List*.

---

However, if you are trying to access the desired element right after the new page loads then ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the `id` attribute as a `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pass"))).send_keys("blabla78945@gmail.com")
  ```
- Using the *tagName* `<input>` along with `id` attribute as a `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#pass"))).send_keys("blabla78945@gmail.com")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```